# How to truncate excess text in non-wrapping HTML table cell and end with "..."

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a HTML template in which the text that goes into a `<td>` tag will be imported from a database field. The text could be anything from 3 to 200 characters in length, and the `<td>` it goes in to is 100% of the screen width. If the text is too long, to fit in the width of the screen, I would like it to be truncated and end with "..."

I could make it so it only imports a certain amount of characters from the field, however, there's no point trying to decide on something as the screen width of the devices this can be viewed on varies dramatically (750 to 1920 pixels) so it needs to show as much as possible for that screen, but cannot wrap as the height of the table rows needs to be fixed.

So instead of:

```
|Text within this cell is too long to fit in this|table cell
```

Would become

```
|Text within this cell is too long to fit in t...|
```

Ideally the "..." would be a hyperlink (as there is another page where this text exists in full.)

Javascript solution would be OK but preferred CSS/HTML5 if possible.

Comment: A script solution would probably be along the lines of looking at the size of the empty cell, then adding the text to a div with no wrap to see if it's bigger. If so, reduce the number of characters until it's smaller by the width of an ellipsis at least. Then replace the extra text with an ellipsis that's a link to the full text.  Likely easier to use panpiper's answer though. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the CSS property `text-overflow: ellipsis`. While the inserted ellipsis cannot be used as a link, you could add a "read more" link to accomplish this.

Comment: I am so relieved at this solution! Was getting worried it would not be possible..

Comment: realised the examples I looked at online where only showing div ellipses, which I later went on to find out these do not apply to td tags as well. I found a solution (a fair bit more code) which I will post later. There are also other things that need to be in place for ellipses to work.